# Private operator delete triggers compile-time error with GCC and Clang but not with MSVC

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, private, new-operator, delete-operator

Motivated by [this not very well asked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51083176/580083), I believe the problem deserves a new standalone clearly titled question. The following code triggers a compilation error with GCC 8.1.0 and Clang 6.0.0, but not with MSVC 19.00:

```
class X {
   public:
      X() /* noexcept */ { }    
   private:
      static void operator delete(void*) { }
};

int main() { 
    X* x = new X{}; 
}
```

From [expr.new](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#21):

> If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the new-expression. **If no unambiguous matching deallocation function can be found, propagating the exception does not cause the object's memory to be freed.** [ *Note:* This is appropriate when the called allocation function does not allocate memory; otherwise, it is likely to result in a memory leak. — *end note* ]

In fact, this does not imply that the compilation error should be triggered if the matching deallocation function `::operator delete` cannot be found. Or, does making it private just results in something like *can be found but cannot be accessed*? Which compilers are right?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://rextester.com/QBL46016). `error C2248: 'X::operator delete': cannot access private member declared in class 'X'`

Comment: @rustyx Uncomment `noexcept`. (For me, it originally compiled even without it, weird.) Anyway, the Standard  does not say anything about `noexcept` specifier in [expr.new].

Comment: The latest MSVC 2017 (19.14 / 15.7.4) accepts the version *with* `noexcept`. But interestingly the Intellisense (based on the EDG front end) still puts a red squiggle under the new and says that it shouldn't compile.

Comment: @BoPersson Not that interesting; intellisense uses a completely different compiler & build chain than actually building.

Comment: @rustyx Still I don't understand why the compilers throw errors without `noexcept`? That paragraph indicates otherwise in my opinion, doesn't it?

Comment: @Yakk - The interesting part is that, historically, the EDG compiler has been correct a lot more times than VC++ itself.  If we have found a case where VC++ is correct, but EDG, g++ and clang are all wrong, that would be an extremely rare occasion. (So probably not).

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions here:

1. How is `operator delete` found even though it's private?

C++ first tries to find a name *anywhere*; checking access protection is a later phase.
Thus, your `operator delete` is found, but inaccessible.

2. Why must my `operator delete` be accessible when the constructor is `noexcept`?

The wording "If any part of the object initialization [...] terminates by throwing an exception" suggests that the rest of the paragraph doesn't apply because of the `noexcept`.

However, as suggested by "any part of...", there may be exceptions inbetween the allocation and entering the constructor (while evaluating initialisers), or after exiting the constructor (while destroying initialisers).

Consider

```
struct Y
{
    Y() {}
    Y(const Y&) { throw "sorry"; }
};

class X {
   public:
      X(Y y) noexcept { }    
   private:
      static void operator delete(void*) { }
};

int main() { 
    Y y;
    X* x = new X{y}; 
}
```

where the `Y` copy constructor throws before you enter `X`'s constructor, but after allocation, so the memory needs to be released.

So I think Visual C++ is wrong (again).

Comment: _"before you enter X's constructor, but after allocation"_ I did not know that, where is it said?

Comment: @PasserBy - [p19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#19).

Comment: As a data point, VC++ *does* reject the version with the `y` parameter. :-)

Comment: Am I insane, or is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38b667e1b835689d) broken?

Comment: @PasserBy - Why broken? You catch everything.

Comment: @molbdnilo VC rejects your example. Why do you say it's wrong? It doesn't use `delete` when it knows for sure no exception can be thrown.

Comment: @StoryTeller Unless the overloaded `operator new` could be elided, shouldn't there be a `new` in output? Or have I misunderstood what the allocation function means.

Comment: @PasserBy - Yes. p19 says the allocation is sequenced before the expressions in the new initializer. So allocation -> copy `y` -> throw "tantrum". And I see what you mean now. WTF.

Comment: @StoryTeller [Bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86347) filed.

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio is being weird with the `noexcept` specifier. On paper, it shouldn't build. The reason is that the decllocation function is looked up independently from the allocation function.

> [**[expr.new] / 20, 21 and 22**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#21)
>
> If the *new-expression* creates an object or an array of objects of
>   class type, access and ambiguity control are done for the allocation
>   function, the deallocation function, and the constructor. If the
>   *new-expression* creates an array of objects of class type, the
>   destructor is potentially invoked.
>
> If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by
>   throwing an exception and a suitable deallocation function can be
>   found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which
>   the object was being constructed, after which the exception continues
>   to propagate in the context of the new-expression. If no unambiguous
>   matching deallocation function can be found, propagating the exception
>   does not cause the object's memory to be freed.
>
> If the new-expression begins with a unary ​`::​` operator, the
>   deallocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.
>   Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type `T` or an array
>   thereof, the deallocation function's name is looked up in the scope of
>   `T`. If this lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is
>   not a class type or array thereof, the deallocation function's name is
>   looked up in the global scope.

According to p20, the deallocation function *has* to be looked up since we are creating a class object. Then the deallcoation function is found successfully, and is unambiguous (it's the member). Since access specifiers are checked only after name lookup, this should cause an error. GCC and Clang are correct.