# Private delete operator complie-time error with gcc but not clang

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

this is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084262/private-operator-delete-triggers-compile-time-error-with-gcc-and-clang-but-not-w#51084262)

when using nothrow allocators the code compile with clang6.0.0 but not with gcc8.1

```
#include <new>

class X {
   public:
      X() noexcept { }    
   private:
      static void operator delete(void*) { }
};

int main() { 
    X* x = new(std::nothrow) X{}; 
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cnew%3E%0A%0Aclass+X+%7B%0A+++public:%0A++++++X()+noexcept+%7B+%7D++++%0A+++private:%0A++++++static+void+operator+delete(void*)+%7B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B+%0A++++X*+x+%3D+new(std::nothrow)+X%7B%7D%3B+%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:24.69973890339426,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:38.329008977580585,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:4.673922498001762,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+8.1',t:'0')),k:32.2973296210234,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

which compiler is right ?

Comment: Which compiler versions do you use?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen latest for both

Comment: Does the linked answer not answer your question?

Comment: @Barry from what i understood i think clang is right but i am really unsure